# objc incompatible pointer type with protocol inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objc-protocol

I am running with Xcode version 5.1, iOS SDK version 7.1.
Here are some sample declarations all in the same file:

```
@protocol A <NSObject>
@end

@protocol B <A>
@end

@interface SomeObject : NSObject <B>
@end

@interface SomeContainer : NSObject
- (id<A>)pop;
@end
```

Xcode generates a warning in the following code:

```
SomeContainer *container = [[SomeContainer alloc] init];
SomeObject *obj = [container pop]; // Warning: Initializing 'SomeObject *__strong' with and expression of incompatible type 'id<A>'
```

I know that typecasting will get rid of the warning, however, I don't understand why I need it. SomeObject must implement whatever is declared in protocol A. Is there something that I am missing? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is because `SomeObject` is something more than just `id<A>`. It's like initialising an object of derived class with pointer to the base class. You can initialize an instance of `id<A>` with `SomeObject` but when you do it vice versa you're receiving a warning, which says :"Hey, buddy you've just assigned base to derived, i.e. something that is present in derived `(SomeObject *)`  may be missed in base `id<A>`"

for example `SomeObject` may contain method `foo` which is not present in protocol `A`, but now after that assignment of yours if you send `foo` message to `obj` it may crash, because `id<A>` is not necessarily has this method. It can, if it's also an instance of `SomeObject`, but it can be anything, which NECESSARILY responds only to the methods declared in `A`.

I hope all this makes sense